# Regex for e mail id which will allow only spcific numbers of dots(1-5) after @ the sign

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

People have discussed a lot on Regex for email validations.
I found many ideal regex for email id but all of them are validating email id having more than 2 dots
i.e.

```
sangram@ab.cd.ef.gh.ij.kl.mn.op
```

All regex are validating this email id which is not right.

its a wrong email id according to me, i understand there can be sub -sub -sub domains , but still more than 5 dots should not be allowed.

i want this thing to be controlled and only 1 to 5 dots can be entered after the @ sign.

so how this can be done using regex ?

Thanks in advance.
i hope that stackoverflow will solve this problem for sure.

-Sangram

Comment: I don't know if .op is actually a toplevel domain, but if it were, your example might be a valid email address. There is no use in disallowing it, while still allowing hahathereisnodomainhere.com.

Comment: yes, it is valid email but i dont want user to enter 100 dots after an email address :-) thats why we have settled the limit to 5 dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this can help. (Mind you it's is a reduced down validation)

```
\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.){1,5}[A-Za-z]{2,4}\Z
```

Comment: Hi @Sangram :), which comment are you addressing ?

Comment: (Mind you it's is a reduced down validation) this comment

Comment: Oh I see, you know the part before the @ char can contain symbols or more accurately punctuations other than those that I wrote in the regex _%+-, that's why I called it reduced down.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think there is a maximum on the number of subdomains possible in an email address.

In any case, it is pointless to try to perfectly match valid email addresses with a regex. No matter how baroque your regex, it will allow countless invalid email addresses through, since you don't know if a syntactically correct domain is an actual domain, or if a "correct" user name is actually accepting email.

Use this pattern:

```
/^[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ ]+$/
```

and be done with it.  More about this at [humane email validation](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200908/humane_email_validation.html).

Comment: Actually, the local part of the email address may contain spaces.

Comment: @Jens: you should read the rest of the Humane Email Validation article: it recommends that if an email fails this regex, then you ask the user, "That looks odd, are you sure?" and if they say yes, then you accept the email.

Comment: @Sangram: Yeah. "Ned Batchelder"@example.com is a valid email address. See here: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Comment: I did =) I just thought I comment here, because not everyone would do so.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 2822](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Simplified version :

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```